# How to compare multiple columns the aggregate the values tied to those columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet of projects which uses import range to collect hours per user per project.
What I'd like to have is a way of totalling these projects hours so I know how many hours each user has given me across all the projects.
Not all projects have the same number of users, and not all users are in every project.

The number of projects will always keep growing so the formula needs to be reactive if possible

[I have made a sample test sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DlxciK2Rb3mg8Z86k7b6Sym1VU2rsVNgfwLw-Eibt1M/edit?usp=sharing)

| Master List Of Users | Total Hours | User | Hours | User | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fred | 5 | Fred | 3 | Harry | 5 |
| Bob | 12 | Bob | 7 | Fred | 2 |
| Cuthbert | 0 | Reginald | 4 | Algernon | 4 |
| Cedric | 0 |  |  | Bob | 5 |
| Algernon | 4 |  |  | Reginald | 6 |
| Rupert | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| Reginald | 10 |  |  |  |  |
| Harry | 5 |  |  |  |  |

I have tried using query but I get confused when trying to collate multiple columns of data.
There is probably an extremely simple way of doing this that I'm just not seeing.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 - I was also using =FILTER({I4:I;L4:L;O4:O;R4:R;U4:U;X4:X;AA4:AA;AD4:AD;AG4:AG;AJ4:AJ;AM4:AM;AP4:AP;AS4:AS;AV4:AV;AY4:AY;BB4:BB;BE4:BE;BH4:BH;BK4:BK;BN4:BN;BQ4:BQ;BT4:BT;BW4:BW;BZ4:BZ;CC4:CC;CF4:CF;CI4:CI;CL4:CL;CO4:CO;CR4:CR;CU4:CU;CX4:CX;DA4:DA},
LEN({I4:I;L4:L;O4:O;R4:R;U4:U;X4:X;AA4:AA;AD4:AD;AG4:AG;AJ4:AJ;AM4:AM;AP4:AP;AS4:AS;AV4:AV;AY4:AY;BB4:BB;BE4:BE;BH4:BH;BK4:BK;BN4:BN;BQ4:BQ;BT4:BT;BW4:BW;BZ4:BZ;CC4:CC;CF4:CF;CI4:CI;CL4:CL;CO4:CO;CR4:CR;CU4:CU;CX4:CX;DA4:DA})) for one of the columns to collate users and =FILTER({I4:I;L4:L;O4:O;R4:R;U4:U;X4:X;AA4:AA;AD4:AD;AG4:AG;AJ4:AJ;AM4:AM;AP4:AP;AS4:AS;AV4:AV;AY4:AY;BB4:BB;BE4:BE;BH4:BH;BK4:BK;BN4:BN;BQ4:BQ;BT4:BT;BW4:BW;BZ4:BZ;CC4:CC;CF4:CF;CI4:CI;CL4:CL;CO4:CO;CR4:CR;CU4:CU;CX4:CX;DA4:DA},
LEN({I4:I;L4:L;O4:O;R4:R;U4:U;X4:X;AA4:AA;AD4:AD;AG4:AG;AJ4:AJ;AM4:AM;AP4:AP;AS4:AS;AV4:AV;AY4:AY;BB4:BB;BE4:BE;BH4:BH;BK4:BK;BN4:BN;BQ4:BQ;BT4:BT;BW4:BW;BZ4:BZ;CC4:CC;CF4:CF;CI4:CI;CL4:CL;CO4:CO;CR4:CR;CU4:CU;CX4:CX;DA4:DA})) to collate hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of your current data, you can try the following:

**Total (sum of hours):**

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A3:A),C3:C + D3:D,""))
```

OR

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(C3:D12,(transpose(COLUMN(C3:D3)^0))))
```

**Project 1:**

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A3:A),SUMIF(F3:F,A3:A,G3:G),""))
```

[image]

**Project 2:**

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A3:A),SUMIF(I3:I,A3:A,J3:J),""))
```

**Etc ...**

Comment: Excellent, Thank you.